# Issues using a variable in monkeyrunner's ".installPackage()"

Tags: android, python, windows, monkeyrunner

I haven't been able to find much on this topic. 
I am trying to automate application testing, to where I place an app in a particular folder and I run the script: `monkeyrunner.bat -v ALL myscript.py`, and the script executes on whatever apk is in the folder called `apkrepository`. This makes it to where I do not have to alter my python script every time I test a new application.

The part where I am running into trouble is I am trying to use a variable for `device1.installPackage()`
See below for the code leading upto it.

```
installme = os.popen(r'dir C:\users\uname\desktop\apkrepository /A:-d /B').read()
print installme
# => com.application.android.apk #or whatever the package name is

filepath = r'C:\users\uname\desktop\apkrepository'

androidapp = filepath + '\\\' + installme

print androidapp
# => C:\users\uname\desktop\apkrepository\com.application.android.apk
#This exactly what I type below manually to get it to work 

device1= MonkeyRunner.waitForConnection(15, "emulator-5554")
#Emulator was started in previous section of code, which is not shown here.

device1.installPackage(androidapp)
#DOES NOT WORK!!

device1.installPackage('c:\users\uname\desktop\apkrepository\com.application.android.apk')
 #The only way it works seems to be to write the path in manually everytime.
```

I have tried many different ways to get this to work correctly, and I wasn't sure if it was something in the way(s) I was/were trying to do it. If the variable prints the correct file path I do not see how it would have issues working. This is probably something really easy, but this is where I am stuck. The error it gives:

```
E/Device: Error dyring Sync: Local Path does not exist. Error installing package C:\users\uname\desktop\apkrepository\com.application.android.apk
```

I am using windows 7 64 bit with python2.7 and the android sdk.

Thank you for any input/assistance provided! I have been stumped by this for a couple days.

Variables DO work for other places (monkeyrunner affiliated classes), like the `device1.startActivity(component=runcomponent)`, where runcomponent is a combination of package + activity variables. *Also note*: I showed both `device1.installPackages` side by side for easy viewing. I do **not** run both in a row on my script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried the same in linux machine, it works. Please have a look at the monkeyrunner script.

```
#! /usr/bin/env monkeyrunner
import re
import sys
import os
import java
import glob
import os

from com.android.monkeyrunner import MonkeyRunner, MonkeyDevice
device1= MonkeyRunner.waitForConnection(15, "emulator-5554")
mydir="/home/user/apk"
os.chdir(mydir)
for files in glob.glob("*.apk"):
    print files
    print "path " ,os.path.abspath(mydir+"/"+files)
    device1.installPackage(mydir+"/"+files)
```

Comment: Let me know if this approach works on windows or not. Otherwise I will try on windows

Comment: I had to do a mydir= r'C:\users\uname\apk' versus mydir = "C:\users\uname\apk" (because the \a does something special in python)

But otherwise, I added the that os.chdir and then the for block you used and everything worked! Thanks!
I wasn't sure what the deal was with what I was trying to do.